# using awk with find -exec

Tags: unix, find, awk

I have a directory structure with 14 directories containing a bunch of files containing data in a three-column format (separated with tabs). I intended to use find and awk to extract the second column from each of those files and output it with the same filename but under a different root folder. Here the sketch of my directory.

data/all -> AA, AB, AC, AD ... (A* being folders containing the files with data stored in a 3-column format, e.g. AA100.txt, AA101.txt ...)

i want to have the modified (one-column) files with the same name, but all under a new root directory data/pos (as opposed to data/all/) -> AA, AB, AC, AD ... (again, each containing A*100.txt, A*101...)

My try was to use find -exec and to give it the awk command, but I'm having issues with outputting the file to the right place.

when being in data/all/

> > find * -type f -exec awk '{print$2}' '{}' > ../pos/'{}' \;

However {} as wildcard for the input file doesn't seem to work when outputting the file?

What am I doing wrong? (I'm on a ubuntu server btw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try without find, if all you want is all the files. While in `data/all/`, run this:

```
for file in ./*; do awk '{print$2}' "$file" > "../pos/$(basename $file)"; done
```

If you want to cover the files in the whole hierarchy under `/data/all`, you can enable the `globstar` option if you are using bash (I believe this would "just work" on zsh) and then use `**` to match all files:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in ./**; do awk '{print$2}' "$file" > "../pos/$(basename $file)"; done
```

Comment: Using `for */*` did the trick for me though, the globstar option wasn't available for me.

Answer (score 6):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are using the redirection `> ../pos/'{}'` as if it was handled by `find` or `awk` but redirections are handled by the shell. In your case it means that you can redirect only output of the whole `find` (not output of `awk`).

Note that you do not usually need to use wildcard like `*` for the starting path of `find`. Is the common way `find .` what you wanted to do or is there any reason for `find *`?

### Solutions

Here we will keep the flexibility of `find` in contrast to the solution by Jacobo de Vera.
Run `awk` in a shell loop:

```
find . -type f -print0 |
  while read -r -d $'\0' x; do
    awk '{print $2}' "$x" > "../pos/$(basename "$x")"
  done
```

The original way with `-exec` will be less efficient because for every file a shell will be launched in addition to `awk` and the multi-level escaping is pretty complicated here:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'awk "{print \$2}" "{}" > "../pos/{}"' \;
```

There could also be an alternative solution of doing the redirection inside `awk`.

Comment: I used the wildcard `*` in order to avoid the avoid the `./` in the path (as it gave me an error message that it could not find the specified path, which was something like `pos/./AA/AA101.txt` -> I had assumed the error to be there, that's why I used the * instead)

Answer (score -1):

find /path -exec ls -l {} \; | awk '{print$1}'